# Project Euler 3 on Python

Tags: python

I'm thinking about the [3rd problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) on Project Euler. I already have the solution, but it's **too long.**

---

Here is my code:

```
def check_prime_number(prime_number):

    for i in range(2, int(prime_number / 2)):
        
        if prime_number % i == 0:
            return False
            
    return True

def find_divisors(number):

    for divisor in range(int(number / 2), 2, -1):

        if check_prime_number(divisor) and number % divisor == 0:
            number /= divisor
            
            print(divisor)
            break

find_divisors(600851475143)
```

---

How to work with long numbers like 600581475143 in Python?

Comment: Python has infinite precision integers. What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
def max_prime_divisor(limit):
    primes = [2]
    answer = None
    if limit % 2 == 0:
        answer = 2
    for i in range(3, int(limit ** .5) + 1, 2):
        inner_limit = int(i ** .5)
        is_prime = True
        for prime in primes:
            if prime > inner_limit:
                break
            if i % prime == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
        if is_prime:
            primes.append(i)
            if limit % i == 0:
                answer = i
    return answer


print(max_prime_divisor(600851475143))
```

Output:

```
6857
```

`

Comment: `def check_prime_number(prime_number):

    for i in range(2, int(prime_number / 2)):
        
        if prime_number % i == 0:
            return False
            
    return True

def find_divisors(number):

    for divisor in range(2, int(number / 2)):

        if check_prime_number(divisor) and number % divisor == 0:
            number /= divisor
            
            print(divisor)

find_divisors(600851475143)`

Comment: Output: `71, 839, 1471, 6857`.

Comment: @MarK The code you pasted corresponds to the one in the post. Our approaches are different. You're checking for half the values. I'm checking for `sqare root` of the values. Also, the division check involves checking only across the prime numbers.

Comment: @MarK even numbers can't be prime divisors. So, look at the indices of the loop.

Comment: But does it count the `71, 839, 1471 6857` output as a solution?( ﾟヮﾟ)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217554/discussion-between-mark-and-balaji-ambresh).